# Can you pregenerate GUID's on content types?

Tags: linq, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, content-type

A PowerShell script created content types and assigns them to a list.  When running SPMetal to generate the DataContent class file, the GUIDs are only associated with the site collection SPMetal is called from.  The Visual Studio solution's Linq-to-SP queries don't work on another site collection because the PowerShell script creates content types on another site collection with a different GUID.

Is there a way to manually specify the GUID in PowerShell or overwrite the content type's GUID in Visual Studio, so Linq-to-SharePoint queries query the correct content type GUID on any site collection?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to fix the Linq-to-SharePoint queries on custom content types that I could find.  The GUIDs were hard coded into the class file imported into Visual Studio.  The solution would work on one site collection, but not another.

The project had to be recoded to query the list without Linq-to-SP and the data context.

The only problem with this is if you initially pull 100 records, then filter with joins, your results would be less than 100, which is what you initially wanted.  You may have to pull "Take()" more than 100, then finish your join with Take(100) to get the desired quantity.